# Error en sintaxis SQL al realizar una actualización

Tags: php, mysql

He tenido problema para hacer un cambio en un registro de mi base de datos. El error que me marca es el siguiente:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''33''' at line 1

Ese 33 que ven es el ID del registro que se va a actualizar.

Lo curioso es que si por ejemplo le meto el número 33 de manera manual (o el número que sea) en la consulta, sí me hace el cambio respetivo, pero si lo meto por variable me marca ese error.

Estoy programando en PHP.

Adjunto mi código:

```
<?php
require 'conexion.php';
$consulta="UPDATE oportuno SET LUGAR='$_POST[lugar]', EVENTO='$_POST[evento]', ACTOR='$_POST[actor]', DEMANDA='$_POST[demanda]', OBSERVACIONES='$_POST[observaciones]' WHERE ID='$_POST[id]'";
mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location="detalleoportuno.php";</script>';
?>
```

Comment: Elimina las comillas simples `'`

Answer (score 0):

En MySQL los valores de consultas que son numéricos no debes ponerlos rodeados de comillas simples, eso es sólo para valores del tipo `VARCHAR`.

Sugiero que pruebes así, además sacando aparte las variables del POST, para que quede más claro el código:

```
$lugar=$_POST["lugar"];
$evento=$_POST["evento"];
$actor=$_POST["actor"];
$demanda=$_POST["demanda"];
$obs=$_POST["observaciones"];
$id=$_POST["id"];

$consulta="UPDATE oportuno SET LUGAR='$lugar', EVENTO='$evento', ACTOR='$actor', DEMANDA='$demanda', OBSERVACIONES='$obs' WHERE ID=$id";
```

Eso no es válido sólo para un campo  `ID`, sino para cualquier campo no sea `VARCHAR`. Por ejemplo si fuera un booleano, habría que poner  `... WHERE colBooleana=TRUE ...`